# The "<>" operator works in VS2013 but not in VS2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, operators

I have a project that has been developed in Visual Studio 2013 and it contains the following code :

```
<DataMember> Protected _valeur As String = ""

Public Overrides Property valeur As IComparable
  Set(value As IComparable)
    If _valeur <> value Then 
        //Dothings
```

It works great. But when I try to work on the code (freshly pulled from our SVN Repo) in VS2015, it doesn't build and I get the following error :

> Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'String' and 'IComparable'. Use
>   'Is' operator to compare two reference types.

I searched everywhere for differences in operator between the 2 Visual Studio versions and I found nothing. I tried on another machine that also has VS2015, but I still get the error. Am I missing something?

**EDIT :** I resolved the problem in my code by replacing every `<>` statement by `String.CompareTo(String)`. I just don't understand why I had an error message in the first place.

Comment: And did you try to use IS just like it was suggested? I think it's just VS2015 doesn't work the same way for IComparable

Comment: @Mederic : Though the `Is` operator compares the objects' references, what if he only wants to compare the values?

Comment: @VisualVincent then in that case i'm not really sure i haven't used IComparable at all before I would need read up on it

Comment: Yes I did and it works, the solution is quite big though so if I can save myself the trouble of going back and change every <> for IS, I'll be happy. I also want to understand why it's a problem. @Mederic

Comment: @AlexandreBoily No idea for that part maybe @VisualVincent will ba able to put some light. To easily replace `<>` to `Is` you can do `ctrl + H` this will open the replacer menu and you can choose to replace in your whole solution or whole document etc etc

Comment: Maybe it has to do with one of the options and it did value.ToString(). Your best bet would be to use CompareTo

Comment: I don't know your specific issue, but as for the `Is` operator it will compare by object reference rather than by value. I don't know if that will be a problem in this case, but the difference is that if you have for instance two integers - `i = 3`, `j = 3` - and compare them with `=` and `Is`, then `i = j` will return true (because both variables are set to `3`) but `i Is j` will return false (because `i` and `j` are not the same object). -- Ping @Mederic

Comment: I decided to change the faulty statement to "value.CompareTo(_valeur) <> 0" and it seems to work. It still doesn't explain why I have an error in the initial code though.

Comment: That code can only compile in VS2013 with Option Strict Off in effect.  What was new in VS2015 was a complete rewrite of the compiler, better known as the "Roslyn project".  Fairly infamous for breaking old code, especially so in vb.net that appeared to not have been tested as well as C#.  But sometimes intentionally.  Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) to get it from the people that worked on it.